# Remove duplicate rows upon multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with duplicate rows. Some columns have data other have zeros. I want to retain the rows with data and eliminate those with zeros, but I also want to remove duplicates when there is only zeros. Here is an example

```
df =

A   B
x   0
x   1
y   0
y   0
z   1
```

I want it to be

```
A   B
x   1
y   0
z   1
```

I am struggling to drop duplicates hierarchically; first keeping the nonzero rows where columns values are different from zero, and then removing duplicates of the rows with column values are zero.

thank you

Comment: So what have you tried?... show us the code please...

Comment: I am actually stuck.

Comment: Without trying anything? We are not here to write your code for you, but help you with your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort_values` and parameter `keep='last'`:

```
df.sort_values(['A','B']).drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   A  B
1  x  1
3  y  0
4  z  1
```

Update for negative values:

```
df.assign(sortkey = df.B.ne(0))
  .sort_values(['A','sortkey'])
  .drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last')
```

Comment: Just as a curiosity, this worked, but since I have also negative values, the sort is trickier. I will need to sort by absolute values, it seems.

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti added an update to handle negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I was already going to create a new column sorted by absolute values. Looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you can using `groupby`

```
df.groupby('A',as_index=False).B.last()
Out[421]: 
   A  B
0  x  1
1  y  0
2  z  1
```